# Encrypt App.config using aspnet_regiis -pef

Tags: asp.net, security, encryption, web-config, app-config

I use `"%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis -pef "connectionStrings" "C:\documents and settings\bob\projects\myproject"` to encrypt the Web.config files. The same command does not work for App.config. How do I encrypt App.config files?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a bit of necromancy, but i just stumbled on the same problem.

So the answer is to rename **app.config to web.config**
Perform encryption using the command you already use
Rename back **web.config to app.config**

[Link to explanation and examples](http://www.dotnetprofessional.com/blog/post/2008/03/03/Encrypt-sections-of-WebConfig-or-AppConfig.aspx)
Extracted from the link:

> So this is a little strange and the reason is that the tool only works with web.config files, however by renaming, then processing our app.config file we can get the desired result.